# pypi-server on Win11 on private network, can get version, config is set, but pip always fails with WinError 10061

Tags: python, windows, pypi, private-network

I have tried to setup a private pypi-server running on a Windows 11 box on a private network.

I setup the following:

- python 3.9.1
- pypi-server 1.5.1
- pip 20.2.3
- pip.ini in C:\ProgramData\pip
- pip.ini contents:

  `[global]`

  `extra-index-url = http://<host>:8080/simple/`

  `trusted-host = <host>`
- tried running server with following command-lines:

  > pypi-server run ~/packages

  > pypi-server run ~/packages &

  > pypi-server run c:\Users\bmckenzie\packages

  > pypi-server run c:\Users\bmckenzie\packages &

  plus all with combinations of -i <host> -p 8080, just the host, just the port, using localhost for host, not specifying host or port (they are in the pip config anyway)
- surfed to http://<ip address> in browser and got the pypi-server splash page correctly
- surfed to http://<ip address>/simple/ in browser and see the couple of python packages I put in my packages folder
- From command-line, the following works and returns proper version number,

  `pypi-server --version`
- Windows firewall has been completely disabled
- netstat shows python listening on port 8080

But, trying to pip install anything leads to a Win-Error 10061
I have tried Googling this problem, but it seems to always boil down to a firewall problem, lack of active listener on the port, or the pypi-service not running, none of which is my problem.  It looks to me like pypi-service doesn't work on Windows or I am starting it wrong?
Anyone have a clue what I can try?

Answer (score 0):

Aha!  The issue is the pip.ini.  This line:

`extra-index-url = http://<host>:8080/simple/`

should be this:

`index-url = http://<host>:8080/simple/`

That allows it all to work correctly.  Btw, the -v (verbose) flags in pip and pypi-server were very helpful in figuring out the problem.